# MQTT password protected channel

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, home-automation

I am using Mosquitto as my local network mqtt broker and several clients posting and subscribing different channels.

As the clients are authenticated by mosquitto (using the password_file in the configuration) for accessing the broker, is there any way to s**ecure individual channels**?

I like to allow some sensors to control the lights (i.e.) but not every sensor is allowed to control the windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mosquitto supports an ACLs which lets you set which topics a user can subscribe/publish to. Details of how to create a ACL file are included in the mosquitto.conf [man](http://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) page:

> **acl_file file *path***
>
> Set the path to an access control list file. If
>   defined, the contents of the file are used to control client access to
>   topics on the broker.
>
> If this parameter is defined then only the topics listed will have
>   access. Topic access is added with lines of the format:
>
> topic [read|write|readwrite]
>
> The access type is controlled using "read", "write" or "readwrite".
>   This parameter is optional (unless  includes a space character)
>   - if not given then the access is read/write.  can contain the + or # wildcards as in subscriptions.
>
> The first set of topics are applied to anonymous clients, assuming
>   allow_anonymous is true. User specific topic ACLs are added after a
>   user line as follows:
>
> user
>
> The username referred to here is the same as in password_file. It is
>   not the clientid.
>
> It is also possible to define ACLs based on pattern substitution
>   within the topic. The form is the same as for the topic keyword, but
>   using pattern as the keyword.
>
> pattern [read|write|readwrite]
>
> The patterns available for substition are:
>
> %c to match the client id of the client
>
> %u to match the username of the client
>
> The substitution pattern must be the only text for that level of
>   hierarchy. Pattern ACLs apply to all users even if the "user" keyword
>   has previously been given.
>
> Example:
>
> pattern write sensor/%u/data
>
> Allow access for bridge connection messages:
>
> pattern write $SYS/broker/connection/%c/state
>
> If the first character of a line of the ACL file is a # it is treated
>   as a comment.
>
> Reloaded on reload signal. The currently loaded ACLs will be freed and
>   reloaded. Existing subscriptions will be affected after the reload.

Comment: Okay seems to work that way with mosquitto, thought there could be a solution within the mqtt standard. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No, each broker implements ACLs in their own way